# Indexing and partitioning Parquet in S3

Tags: amazon-s3, indexing, amazon-emr, parquet, delta-lake

Is it possible to both index and partition a Parquet file in S3 or is this functionality only available on File Storage types of volumes?

I'm looking for a way to provide researchers to access the same data in S3 via EMR notebooks for (a) generic R and Python scripts, and (b) Spark-enabled querying. But the proprietary solution and query language we have right now provides indexing and partitioning on an NFS store - so I want to preserve this functionality. I see that Delta Lake provides this, but I'm wondering if this can be achieved with simpler tools like Arrow.

Comment: Parquets indices and partitions should be compatible with S3.  I’m fairly certain arrow will support the partitioning across S3 but I don’t know the status of arrow’s support for parquet indexing.  Would you be using the python wrappers?

Comment: To write the data, yes.

Comment: What would you use for queries?  Hive / Presto?

Comment: @Pace err, Spark SQL via pyspark and sparklyr?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Delta lake to Partition a Parquet file. They are also indexed by default.

You can do it like this

```
%sql

CREATE TABLE UsableTable_unpartitioned
USING DELTA
LOCATION 'Location of the Parquet File on S3' ;

CREATE TABLE UsableTable
USING DELTA
PARTITIONED BY (my_partitioned_column)
LOCATION 'MyS3Location'
select * from UsableTable_unpartitioned;

DROP TABLE UsableTable_unpartitioned;
```

Verify your partitions and all the required information created :

```
%sql
describe detail UsableTable
```

You could expose this table using JDBC